# Passing variable as parameter makes it 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, variables, split, undefined

I am currently trying to create a very rudimentary calculator with JS, HTML and CSS. I don't think there is any issue with the CSS so I won't include it for now.

I have a function `setOperand()` that is called upon pressing one of the operation buttons on my calculator. It adds the respective operator to the "display"-div's innerHTML and (for testing purposes) logs it to the console. That part works as intended. At the end it returns the operator as a variable called `operand`.

Now, if the '=' button is pressed, the function `equalsButton()` is called which logs the operand variable once again and here I noticed it logs it's value as *'undefined'*. I find this very strange and have tried solving it for many hours today, trying different approaches and looking for possible mistakes I could've made. I had `operand` defined as *'undefined'* outside a function in order to initialize it but removing that code didn't solve the problem.

I am trying to have `equalsButton()` split the display content into two numbers, by using the operator as the "splitter".

Also, could I just evaluate the `innerHTML` as is? Since the two numbers and the operator are displayed like an equation already.

Thanks in advance for all responses!

```js
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operandButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operand]");
const equals = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const allClear = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]");
const deleteNum = document.querySelector("[data-del]");
const display = document.getElementById("display");

var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
//var operand = undefined;

window.onload = function() {
  alert("page loaded");
};

function buttonPress(display, button) {
  let currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = currentContent + button;
}

function setOperand(display, operator) {
  currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = currentContent + operator;
  var operand = display.innerHTML.slice(-1);
  console.log(operand); // operator
  return operand;
}

function equalsButton(display, operand) {
  console.log(operand); // for some reason operand here is 'undefined'. Fix?
  splitNum = display.innerText.split(String(operand));
  num1 = splitNum[0];
  num2 = splitNum[1];
  console.log(num1); // 3+2 in my test
  console.log(num2); // undefined
  return num1, num2;
}

function calculate(display, operand, num1, num2) {
  if (operand == "+") {
    let result = num1 + num2;
  } else if (operand == "-") {
    let result = num1 - num2;
  } else if (operand == "*") {
    let result = num1 * num2;
  } else if (operand == "/") {
    let result = num1 / num2;
  }
  display.innerHTML = result;
}

function del(display) {
  display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
  return display;
}

function allclear(display, num1, num2, operand) {
  display.innerHTML = "";
  var operand = undefined;
  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  return num1, num2, operand;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="vie wport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Online Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="display" class="display"></div>
  <div class="numpad">
    <button onclick="allclear(display, num1, num2, operand)" class="button">
        AC
      </button>
    <button onclick="del(display)" class="button">DEL</button>
    <button onclick="equalsButton(display)" class="button dbl-hor">=</button>

    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 1)" class="button">1</button>
    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 2)" class="button">2</button>
    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 3)" class="button">3</button>

    <button onclick="setOperand(display, '+')" class="button dbl-ver">
        +
      </button>

    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 4)" class="button">4</button>
    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 5)" class="button">5</button>
    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 6)" class="button">6</button>

    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 7)" class="button">7</button>
    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 8)" class="button">8</button>
    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 9)" class="button">9</button>

    <button onclick="setOperand(display, '-')" class="button single">
        -
      </button>

    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, button)" class="button">.</button>

    <button onclick="buttonPress(display, button)" class="button">0</button>

    <button onclick="setOperand(display, '*')" class="button">*</button>
    <button onclick="setOperand(display, '/')" class="button">/</button>
  </div>
  <script src="calculator.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The project is WIP and some code outside of the 2 functions might be redundant.

Comment: `equalsButton(display)` will only pass one argument, not two. If you want to use the second parameter, pass a second argument to the function.

Comment: Look up how variables work in js, you can't just randomly declare them at any point in your code and expect them to be available anywhere

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried Making it lets complex;**

```js
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operandButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operand]");
const equals = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const allClear = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]");
const deleteNum = document.querySelector("[data-del]");
const display = document.getElementById("display");

var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
//var operand = undefined;

window.onload = function () {
  alert("page loaded");
};

function buttonPress(display, button) {
  let currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = currentContent + button;
}

function setOperand(display, operator) {
  currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = currentContent + operator;
  var operand = display.innerHTML.slice(-1);
  console.log(operand); // operator
  return operand;
}

function equalsButton(display) {
const innerText = display.innerText;
 let operand = innerText.includes('+') ? '+' : innerText.includes('-') ? '-' : innerText.includes('/') ? '/':'*'
  console.log(operand); // for some reason operand here is 'undefined'. Fix?
  splitNum = display.innerText.split(operand);
  num1 = splitNum[0];
  num2 = splitNum[1];
  console.log(num1); // 3+2 in my test
  console.log(num2); // undefined
  return num1, num2;
}

function calculate(display, operand, num1, num2) {
  if (operand == "+") {
    let result = num1 + num2;
  } else if (operand == "-") {
    let result = num1 - num2;
  } else if (operand == "*") {
    let result = num1 * num2;
  } else if (operand == "/") {
    let result = num1 / num2;
  }
  display.innerHTML = result;
}

function del(display) {
  display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
  return display;
}

function allclear(display, num1, num2, operand) {
  display.innerHTML = "";
  var operand = undefined;
  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  return num1, num2, operand;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="vie wport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Online Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="display" class="display"></div>
    <div class="numpad">
      <button onclick="allclear(display, num1, num2, operand)" class="button">
        AC
      </button>
      <button onclick="del(display)" class="button">DEL</button>
      <button onclick="equalsButton(display)" class="button dbl-hor">=</button>

      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 1)" class="button">1</button>
      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 2)" class="button">2</button>
      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 3)" class="button">3</button>

      <button onclick="setOperand(display, '+')" class="button dbl-ver">
        +
      </button>

      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 4)" class="button">4</button>
      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 5)" class="button">5</button>
      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 6)" class="button">6</button>

      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 7)" class="button">7</button>
      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 8)" class="button">8</button>
      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, 9)" class="button">9</button>

      <button onclick="setOperand(display, '-')" class="button single">
        -
      </button>

      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, button)" class="button">.</button>

      <button onclick="buttonPress(display, button)" class="button">0</button>

      <button onclick="setOperand(display, '*')" class="button">*</button>
      <button onclick="setOperand(display, '/')" class="button">/</button>
    </div>
    <script src="calculator.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont pass variables as parameter (when defining a function), only as arguments (when calling a function).
In your case, when you define `equalsButton(display, operand)`, "display and "operand" become brand new variables with the same name, which overwrite the previous defined variables, inside of the curly braces of the function definition.

```js
// function definition (num1, num2 are parameters)
function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2
}

// function call (2, 3 are arguments)
add(2, 3)

let number1 = 2;
let number2 = 4;

// no parameters needed since always add the same two variables
function addVariables() {
  return number1 + number2
}

console.log(addVariables()) // logs: 6

number1 = 5;
console.log(addVariables()) // logs: 9
```

I pointed out a few bugs.
I describe them with "//*"-comments so you can search with ctrl+f
and put the corresponding solution below in a "//="-comment that you can copy and replace the line below with it.

```js
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operandButton = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operand]");
const equals = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const allClear = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]");
const deleteNum = document.querySelector("[data-del]");
const display = document.getElementById("display");

var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
//* initialize operand variable
//=var operand;
//var operand = undefined;

window.onload = function () {
  alert("page loaded");
};

function buttonPress(display, button) {
  let currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = currentContent + button;
}

function setOperand(display, operator) {
  //* dont forget to initialize constant currentContent
  //=const currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  currentContent = display.innerHTML;
  display.innerHTML = currentContent + operator;
  var operand = display.innerHTML.slice(-1);
  console.log(operand); // operator
  return operand;
}

//* omit parameter operand
//=function equalsButton(display) {
function equalsButton(display, operand) {
  console.log(operand); // for some reason operand here is 'undefined'. Fix?
  //* dont forget to initialize constant currentContent
  //=const splitNum = display.innerText.split(String(operand));
  splitNum = display.innerText.split(String(operand));
  num1 = splitNum[0];
  num2 = splitNum[1];
  console.log(num1); // 3+2 in my test
  console.log(num2); // undefined
  return num1, num2;
}

function calculate(display, operand, num1, num2) {
  //* declare variable result before the if's blocks.
  //=let result;
  if (operand == "+") {
    //* omit the let key. since you would declare a new variable that only exists in the surrounding curly brackets
    //=result = num1 + num2;
    let result = num1 + num2;
  } else if (operand == "-") {
    //=result = num1 + num2;
    let result = num1 - num2;
  } else if (operand == "*") {
    //=result = num1 + num2;
    let result = num1 * num2;
  } else if (operand == "/") {
    //=result = num1 + num2;
    let result = num1 / num2;
  }
  display.innerHTML = result;
}

function del(display) {
  display.innerHTML = display.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
  return display;
}

function allclear(display, num1, num2, operand) {
  display.innerHTML = "";
  var operand = undefined;
  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  return num1, num2, operand;
}
```